# How can I make a list of letter groups?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a series of letters:

```
a, b, d, e, f, g, h, i, l, u, ü
```

How can I get them grouped and ranged so that someMagicFunction('a, b, d, e, f, g, h, i, l, u, ü')

returns something like this:

```
[
    "a-b"
    "d-g"
    "h-i"
    "l",
    "u-ü"
]
```

Is this easy to do?

NB: There may also be characters like: ö, ä, ü, ß etc.

Comment: what is the logic behind this output?

Comment: I need to do this for a project I'm doing

Comment: ok, but what decides how you group the letters. The first group is 2 chars, the second 4, then 2, then 1. What governs this?

Comment: The OP want maybe to group by continuous letters in the alphabetical order. But how to group special characters like `ä` ? Is it like the letter `a` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I misunderstood. huggilou is right. I want to group continuous characters. I added more to the example to include umlaut and how that should be grouped.

The letters will also always be lowercase, there is no uppercase

Comment: @RISCOS : So your example is incorrect, it should be `d-i` and not `"d-g" + "h-i"`Or there is other things to say ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or are you just expecting a ready solution here?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a rudimentary "magic function" solution. I do wish you would have posted a little more about what you have tried or at least some direction of thinking regarding a solution. I'm also not clear how the special characters are supposed to work, like, are they supposed to be included as part of the normal alphabet?

Anyway, my suggestion is to create an array containing all the letters of the alphabet, in order, including special ones where you need/want them. Then, you iterate over your "series of letters" array (call it `test`), and for every character in it, check if its index in the `alphabet` array is right after the index of the character that comes before it in the `test` array. If not, you can push it into a new space into another array (call it `grouped`).

If it is (as in, if the character comes after the same previous element in both `alphabet` and `test`), you do another check to see if the character *after* it in the `test` array also comes after it in the `alphabet` array. If it does, that means you can just continue to the next iteration of the `test` loop, otherwise, that means the next character in `test` will be a discontinuous character, so you can change the last string you pushed into `grouped` to include `"-"+test[i]`.

```
function someMagicFunction(test){
    var alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o", "ö","p","q","r","s","t","u","ü","v","w","x","y","z"];
    var grouped = [];

    for(var i=0; i<test.length; i++){
        if (grouped.length && alphabet.indexOf(test[i]) - alphabet.indexOf(test[i-1])==1){
            if(alphabet.indexOf(test[i+1])-alphabet.indexOf(test[i])==1)
                continue;
            else grouped[grouped.length-1] += "-"+test[i];
        }
        else 
            grouped.push(test[i]);
    }
    return grouped;
}

var series = ["a", "b", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "l", "u", "ü"];
console.log(someMagicFunction(series));
```

You can view the results at JSBin: http://jsbin.com/kigozelaji/1/edit?js,console